# What is ELF Header in xv6?

Tags: linker, operating-system, executable, elf, xv6

What is ELF header? Can anyone explain in detail how it works and why is it required? I can't find any good resource which provides a crisp explanation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELF header is at the start of the executable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format